# Is there any resourcedictionary navigation on visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xaml

I need resource dictionary navigation tool like Expression Blend. Because my xaml file is too long and hard to navigate to style.

Is there any resource dictionary navigation add-on on visual studio 2008?

How to easy navigate to resource dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of such an add-on, but if your XAML gets too large, create user controls for defined features of your page and use them in the main page.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider breaking out your resource dictionary to other resource dictionaries - based on logical grouping - and then using merged dictionaries to bring it all back to the current resource dictionary.

HTH